# Bandpass fundamental and harmonics in Matlab

Tags: matlab, bandpass, comb

I have a signal in time domain whose sample frequency is Fs=25600. I would like to remove from the fundamental F=285Hz and all its harmonics (2*F,3*F,etc). I tried to use the comb filter in Matlab using this code :

```
Fs=25600;
N=43;
BW=285;
Apass=200;
[b, a] = iircomb(N, BW/(Fs/2), Apass);
Hd= dfilt.df2(b, a);
x1 = filter(b, a, signal);
```

Here is the spectrum of the original signal over the frequency interval up to around 400Hz
[image]

Here is the result after applying the filter cited above:
[image]
I don't get the awaited result. Is there a way to accomplish this in Matlab?

Comment: Can you share the signal file with us?

Comment: Can you please show your input and output signals, designed filter impulse response and frequency response etc, both as plots and as data files appreciated...

Comment: @Fat32 I've shared the spectra

Comment: Nice. What about the filter? Please also plot its frequency response. It's bettter if you plot the full spectrum of the filter. Not everybody has the access to the function **iircomb**. It will be better if you could also upload the filter coefficients *a* and *b* for similar reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with the comb filter design. According to Matlab documentation the following line creates the filter you want:

```
[b,a] = iircomb(round(25600/285), 2*285/25600/35,'peak');
```

Looking at the frequency response of the designed filter: [image]

Seems to be able to solve your problem...

Comment: @chsafouane Note that since your fundamental frequency $f_o=285$ Hz do not divide the sampling frequency $F_s = 25600$ Hz in an integer number of times, the **exact** notch/peak frequency you get will not be $285$ Hz by this design method, unless you change your sampling frequency properly. Also note that the Matlab function options *notch* and *peak* do not place the central frequencies at the same place.